# Plotting the contour graph of $f(x,y) = x^3+y^2-3x$

Tags: partial-derivative, graphing-functions

$f(x,y) = x^3+y^2-3x$

Then $H(\vec{x}) = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x \partial y}\\ \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial y \partial x}
 & \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial y^{2}}
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
6x & 0\\ 
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

Let $\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}$ be the eigenvalues of $H(\vec{x})$

Let $\tau = tr(H)$

Let $ \triangle = $det$(H) $

So I found the stationary points:

$P_{1} = (-1, 0)$

$P_{2} = (1,0)$

At $P_{1}$, we have:

$H(P_{1}) = \begin{pmatrix}
-6 & 0\\ 
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix} $

We have $\lambda_{1}<0, \lambda_{2}>0, \tau < 0, \triangle <0 \implies$saddle point at $P_{1}$

At $P_{2}$, we have:

$H(P_{2}) = \begin{pmatrix}
-6 & 0\\ 
 0& 2
\end{pmatrix}$

$\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2} > 0, \triangle >0, \tau > 0 \implies$ minimum at $P_{2}$

I do not know how to go about sketching the graph/how to visualise it. Could someone please provide an answer which includes some general statements about sketching contour plots. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to looks at some images of elliptic curves.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve  
$y^2 = -(x^3 -3x +f(x,y)$ for any level of $f(x,y)$ those curves will trace out contour lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The level curve $f(x,y) = c$ is $y = \pm \sqrt{c + 3x-x^3}$.
Note the symmetry about the $x$ axis.
Of course the quantity inside the square root must be nonnegative for $y$ to be real.
If $c = f(P_1) = 2$, $2 + 3 x - x^3 =  (2-x)(x+1)^2$, so this is $0$ at $x= -1$ and $x=2$, positive on both sides of $x=-1$, but negative for $x > 2$.
There is a local maximum at $x=1$ in the upper half plane and local minimum at $x=1$ in the lower half plane.
Moreover, as $x \to -\infty$, $\sqrt{c + 3 x - x^3} \sim (-x)^{3/2}$.  Thus 
the level curve $f(x,y) = 2$ looks like this:

[image]

For $ c > 2$, $\sqrt{c+3x - x^3}$ will be positive for all $x$ up to some value $> 2$.  The curve will be on the "outside" of the previous one.  In the upper half plane the curve has 
a local minimum  at $x=-1$, local maximum at $x=1$. Again there is symmetry
about the $x$ axis.

For $-2 < c < 2$, where $-2 = f(P_2)$, the curve has two parts, one to the left of the $c=2$ curve in $x < -1$, the other a closed loop inside the loop of the $c=2$ curve.  For $c < -2$, there is no closed loop.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a couple of questions- if you don't mind. How do you know which values of $c$ to consider? (I notice you didn't go below $-2$). Also, on the second diagram does the distance between the circular lines reflect the gradient? And I presume green means positive, whilst red means negative - but what do the other colours mean?